# stm32f4 fatfs f_write whitemarks

Tags: stm32, fatfs

Im struggling  with fatfs on stm32f4. With no problem i can mount, create file and write on it by  : `char my_data[]="hello world"` and in windows file shows normally but when i try use code as loger :

```
float bmp180Pressure=1000.1;
char presur_1[6];//bufor znakow do konwersji
sprintf(presur_1,"%0.1f",bmp180Pressure);
char new_line[]="\n\r";

if(f_mount(&myFat, SDPath, 1)== FR_OK)
{
    f_open(&myFile, "dane.txt", FA_READ|FA_WRITE); 
    f_lseek(&myFile, f_size(&myFile));//sets end of data
    f_write(&myFile, presur_1, 6, &byteCount);
    f_write(&myFile, new_line,4, &byteCount);
    f_close(&myFile);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15);
}
```

When i was read from computer i have :[top : notepad ++ buttom :windows notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyYVO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two problems in your code:

The string for the number is too short. C strings are terminated with a null byte. So `presur_1` needs to be at least 7 bytes long (6 for the number and 1 for the null byte). Since it's only 6 bytes long, `sprintf` will write beyond the allocated length and destroy some other data.

The string for the newline is initialized with a string of 2 characters (plus the null byte). However, you write 4 characters to the file. So in addition to the newline, a NUL character and a garbage byte will end up in the file.

The fixed code looks like this:

```
float bmp180Pressure = 1000.1;
char presur_1[20];//bufor znakow do konwersji
int presur_1_len = sprintf(presur_1,"%0.1f\n\r",bmp180Pressure);

if(f_mount(&myFat, SDPath, 1)== FR_OK)
{
    f_open(&myFile, "dane.txt", FA_READ|FA_WRITE); 
    f_lseek(&myFile, f_size(&myFile));//sets end of data
    f_write(&myFile, presur_1, presur_1_len, &byteCount);
    f_close(&myFile);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15);
}
```